# Insert SUMIF formula in a range

Tags: excel

Could you please help me on the following issue. Thank you in advance.

I need to insert a SUMIF formula in a range using vba. I could insert a SUM formula in the range. Please see below;

```
ActiveSheet.Range("G" & LastrowAS).Formula = "=SUM(G3 :GG)"
```

But when I try to have SUMIF, I face an error.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("G" & LastrowAS).Formula = "=SUMIFS(G6:GG;G6:GG;"<>#VALUE!"; G6:GG; "<>#N/A")"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JpmM.jpg)

Comment: You can see error from the attached image.

Comment: There's no way that first line works either. `G3:GG` is not a valid range reference.

Comment: I have already defined GG    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("G" & 3 & ":G" & LastrowAS - 1)
        ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="GG", RefersTo:=rng

Comment: Then your issue is the double quotes (they need doubled up), and you have to use `,` instead of `;`. See the linked duplicates. `"=SUMIFS(G6:GG,G6:GG,""<>#VALUE!"",G6:GG,""<>#N/A"")"`

Comment: I had to do that because this formula will be used in a new exported excel file . and every time number of rows is different

Comment: Thank you so much.